# Integrating Demographic Data in R

Tags: r, integration, vlookup, matching

Im hoping to get help. I have two different sheets in an excel workbook and am trying to integrate demographic information from one sheet to match the case numbers with the data in the other sheet. What would be the best way to go about this is an R script?

For example, one sheet contains a unique case ID # and demographic info (race,age, etc) and the other sheet contains the same unique case ID #s and treatment outcomes. I am trying to integrate the data so that I can view a row with the patientsʻ demographic info AND treatment outcomes simultaneously.

Copy and pasting the respective columns into one sheet. However, unique case ID numbers are not in the same order in each spreadsheet.

Comment: Needs many fmore details/specifics before any coding effort can be productively attempted. Read [ask] and [MCVE]. (Efforts to merge datasets do not depend on the ordering if you can specify criteria for the merge.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Import data from xlsx by sheet
2. Join to data frame by keyword ID, and select the fields you need, or everything()

```
library('tidyverse')
library('openxlsx')

data1 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = 'data.xlsx', sheet = 1)
data2 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = 'data.xlsx', sheet = 2)

result <- data1 %>% 
  left_join(data2, by = c('ID'='ID')) %>% 
  select(ID, race, age, outcome)
```